# Пользовательские атрибуты в C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, атрибуты

Я хочу написать свой атрибут, который будет аналогичен `[Authorize(Role = "Admin", Permission = "Create")]` чтобы я смог использовать вот такую конструкцию перед классом. Permission для админа хранятся в отдельной таблице БД.

---

**UPD**

Предполагаемое использование:

```
public ExampleController : Controller{
   ...

   [Authorize(Role = "Admin", Permisson = "Edit")]
   public ActionResult Example(){ }
}
```

Что имеется?

Была идея наследоваться от `AuthorizeAttribute` и добавить свойство `Permissions`

```
public class ExampleAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private string[] allowedUsers;
        private string[] allowedRoles;
        private string[] allowedPermission;

        public string Permissions
        {
            set
            {
                allowedPermission = value.Split(',', ' ').ToArray();
            }
        }

        public ExampleAuthorizeAttribute(string[] users, string[] roles)
        {
            allowedUsers = users;
            allowedRoles = roles;
        }
        // здесь перед return проверить Permissions
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated && hasUser(httpContext) && hasRole(httpContext);
        }

        private bool hasUser(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return allowedUsers.Length > 0 ? allowedUsers.Contains(httpContext.User.Identity.Name) : true;
        }

        private bool hasRole(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return allowedRoles.Length > 0 ? allowedRoles.Any(role => httpContext.User.IsInRole(role)) : true;
        }
    }
```

И потом использовать, но совсем понятно как в контекст засунуть Permissions пользователя

```
public ExampleController : Controller{
       ...

       [ExampleAuthorize(Role = "Admin", Permisson = "Edit")]
       public ActionResult Example(){ }
    }
```

Но похоже, что не совсем верное решение

p.s. mvc 4

Comment: Понимаю, что не конкретно по сабжу, но вдруг это решит конечную задачу: если ещё не знакомы, то почитайте про **Entity Framework** и **Fluent API**.

Comment: Атрибут — не более чем привешенный кусок бумаги на доске объявлений. Навесить-то вы ваш атрибут навесите, а кто его читать и интерпретировать будет?

Comment: @VladD так вот мне и надо литература, чтобы описать как его интерприровать

Comment: @V.P.: Ну, не думаю, что фреймворк даёт возможность определять свои кастомные атрибуты. Впрочем, может так оно и есть, подождём знатоков.

Comment: @VladD, знатоков в чем? здесь какого-то тэга не хватает?

Comment: @4per: Ну, я не знаю, какой фреймворк имеется в виду. EF, наверное?

Comment: @4per: Да, явно не хватает тега, соответствующего фреймворку, используемому автором вопроса.

Comment: @VladD Да, EntityFramework

Comment: Можете привести пример кода, демонстрирующий как вы это атрибут планируете использовать? На какие классы вы будете навешивать атрибут, какое поведение ожидаете?

Comment: @PrimusSingularis привел.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk http://jacopretorius.net/2010/01/permission-based-access-in-asp-net-mvc.html

Comment: @PrimusSingularis спасибо! Это не совсем то, что нужно, но принцип работы понятен и переделать под свои нужды не составит труда. Оформите в виде ответа, чтобы при недоступности ресурса другие участники могли найти ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток.
Рискну предположить, что вы используете ASP.NET MVC.То как вариант решения:

```
 public class MyAuthAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if(user==null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { 
                { "controller", "Account" }, { "action", "Login" } 
               });
        }
    }
}
```

Подробно почитать сможете [тут](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/8.2.php)

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно. Но возьму на заметку!

Answer (score 0):

Я предположу, что автор имел ввиду что то вроде такого:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class V8VisibleAttribute : Attribute
{
  public string Alias { get; }
  public bool HasDefaultValue { get; set; }
  public V8VisibleAttribute() { }
  public V8VisibleAttribute(string alias)
  {
    this.Alias = alias;
  }
}


public class testComponent
{
  [V8Visible("Версия")]
  public string Version => "1.0";
}
```

И использование:

```
var type = test.GetType();
var info = (System.Reflection.TypeInfo) type;
var props = info.DeclaredProperties.Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof (V8VisibleAttribute))).ToList();
var methods = info.DeclaredMethods.Where(x => !x.IsSpecialName &&  Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(V8VisibleAttribute))).ToList();

foreach (var prop in props)
{
  var v8VisibleAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(V8VisibleAttribute)) as V8VisibleAttribute;
}

foreach (var prop in methods)
{
  var v8VisibleAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(V8VisibleAttribute)) as V8VisibleAttribute;
}
```

[Справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx)